# Android push notification. App started on main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

my Android application listens for **push notification by GCM**.
In the message i put a json object with some information to handle in the app, so i'm able to start different activities based on that.
Here the code for start a PendingIntent :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

...
...
// here i create the pending intent object based on json sent in the notification message from server side
...
...
// add the notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(defaultIcon)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_my_icon))
                    .setContentTitle("My Application")
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setVibrate(vibrate)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

What is not clear to me is why, **if the app is not running**, the app is started on the main activity. What i want is that it reamins closed until the user click on the notification. Is that possibile? There is a way?

Thanks
Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want is that it reamins closed until the user click on the notification.

Should be possible. Don't give your "Main Activity" a layout, do your work to show the notification and put an Intent for onClick notification action into the 
NotificationBuilder. Close the activity directly afterwards.
Catch this intent with another activity (put another 
Activity class into the intent), that has a layout.

edit:

You could also apply a transparent app theme to your main activity, to avoid
popping up a black screen for some milliseconds.

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
  </style>
```

Use it in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"
```

Comment: Thanks JasksOnF1re! This is a good solution and i accept it. What i'm thiking is how famous applications like Whatsapp messenger implements it. Infact, on a new message on the chat, the application isn't started. Only if i click on notification it is opened. Due to the fact that i can "connect" a particular acitivty on the notification message ( there is a specific method "setContentIntent" ) sound strange to me that we must implement a "workaround" for that. This is still not clear to me :-)

Comment: I bet they have implemented a service, which listens in background to the push. I am not sure, but i think you can configure gcm to make the service receive the pushes.